# passing and calling multiple arguments in tcl

Tags: batch-file, arguments, tcl

I want to make a tcl procedure that can take `N` number of arguments. And I want to call it from a bat file.
This is the procedure I wrote:

```
proc multi_argu {args} {
foreach {path rev_start rev_end} $args {
        puts "path-> $path"
        puts "rev_start-> $rev_start"
        puts "rev_end-> $rev_end"
    }
}
multi_argu $argv
```

Now I call it from my bat file as

```
tclsh multi_argu.tcl 1 2 3
```

But the out is

```
path-> 1 2 3
rev_start->
rev_end->
```

At the end of my tcl file, I am calling  `multi_argu $argv` which I think is the culprit. However, I do not know how to do this step for multiple arguments. can anyone provide any input?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since `$argv` is a list, you are passing a list variable to your proc, which means `$args` becomes a list, containing one list element.

In tcl 8.5, you can make a minor change to the way you call the proc:

```
multi_argu {*}$argv
```

The [`{*}`](http://wiki.tcl.tk/17158) will enumerate the items of the list, so `$args` becomes a list of items.

Otherwise, I guess you could use something like:

```
foreach {path rev_start rev_end} [lindex $args 0] { ... }
```

This kind of defeats the purpose of using `args` as the arguments of the proc though. In that case, you could use another variable name too.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have to define multi_argu as a proc? Your .bat file could just call multi_argu.tcl
that contains:

```
puts "Calling $argv0 with $argc arguments: $argv..."

foreach {path rev_start rev_end} $argv {
        puts "path-> $path"
        puts "rev_start-> $rev_start"
        puts "rev_end-> $rev_end"
    }
```

Now when you call it from your bat file as

```
tclsh multi_argu.tcl 1 2 3
```

The output is:

```
Calling multi_argu.tcl with 3 arguments: 1 2 3...
path-> 1
rev_start-> 2
rev_end-> 3
```